# condition_variable throwing system_error with Xcode - fine with VStudio

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm getting an error every time I try waiting on my condition_variable when compiling in Xcode. Error is "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: condition_variable wait failed: Invalid argument"

Everything works fine in Visual Studio 2013. Code works if I decide to not wait on the same condition_variable from multiple threads. Grrrr.

Ok, code.

main.cpp:

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ThreadPool pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pool.sendWork();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50000));
    return 0;
}
```

ThreadPool.h

```
#pragma once
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class ThreadPool
{
protected:
    std::condition_variable     _condition;

private:
    std::vector<std::thread>    _threads;
    void threadLoop();

public:
    ThreadPool();
    void sendWork();
};
```

ThreadPool.cpp:

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

ThreadPool::ThreadPool()
{
    for (unsigned int i {0}; i < 10; ++i)
        _threads.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::threadLoop, this));
}
void ThreadPool::threadLoop()
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock {mutex};
    _condition.wait(lock);            // This is where the crash happens
}

void ThreadPool::sendWork()
{
    _condition.notify_one();
}
```

This is a major simplification of the real code, but it's enough to trigger the crash.

Is this supposed to work? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be more precise, the *Requires* section of the spec of `condition_variable::wait()` is (N3936 §30.5.1 [thread.condition.condvar]/p9):

> ```
> void wait(unique_lock<mutex>& lock);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `lock.owns_lock()` is `true` and `lock.mutex()` is locked by
>   the calling thread, and either
>
> — no other thread is waiting on this `condition_variable` object or
>
> — `lock.mutex()` returns the same value for each of the lock arguments supplied by all concurrently
>   waiting (via `wait`, `wait_for`, or `wait_until`) threads.

Thus, every thread concurrently waiting on a `condition_variable` must pass in the same mutex. It is technically allowed for two threads to wait on a `condition_variable` using one mutex, and then after both wait terminates (and no thread is waiting on the `condition_variable`), for them to both wait on the same object using a different mutex. I do not know whether there are any realistic use cases for this.

Note also that `std::condition_variable_any::wait()` does not have such a requirement. The only requirement on the type supplied is that it meets `BasicLockable` requirements, which basically means that it has `lock()` and `unlock()`.

Answer (score 5):

Your mutex in `ThreadPool::threadLoop` is a local variable. That means that different threads are locking on different mutexes. This is invalid: condition variables are tied to a specific mutex and you must acquire a lock for *that* mutex before waiting on the condition.

You should declare a `_mutex` (or, even better, use the `mutex_` naming convention: underscore-prefix identifiers are mostly reserved) member variable in your `ThreadPool` class, and always lock on *that*.

Comment: I had different problems when I tried that. If that's the way it's "supposed" to work, I'll try that and see what happens. ty

Comment: @MGaz, don't forget that `condition_variable.wait` can return spuriously. Make sure that you check for an actual condition too.